# How can i hide the keyboard when the uitextView is in focus~~

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uitextfield

I hava a `UITextView` ,and after some characters' input, I want to use a button click to hide the keyboard and the `UITextView` is still in focus....**[Attention:the button is not a return key or a done key];**

Comment: try this `[self resignFirstResponder];` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set delegate to your UITextView instance? 
If so, try using `[_textView resignFirstResponder];`

else

Try using `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: Hello,I just try resignFirstResponder，but found that the UitextView lost focus,how about [self.view endEditing:YES]; what's that mean?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean as "lost focus". [self.view endEditing:YES] makes all the views that are under editing (i.e tableview, textview and textfield) to non-editing state.

Comment: He wants to say that textfield is still in editing mode ie focused the curs-sure is in textfield and blinking but the keyboard is hidden

Comment: @AalokParikh, thanks for your explanation. Its seems something wiered.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8350573/1424174 . Is this similar to your case?

Answer (score 0):

mplement following code to your view controller .m file & .h file add delegate of textView

```
 -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
  if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```

Now goto interface builder, select your textview & set return key type done.

Comment: the button is not a return key or a done key,the button click will show a menu,then click a menu item like"UserName" then i can add a string like "jake" to the uitextview