# How to prevent floating keyboard. Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable UITextField keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615806/disable-uitextfield-keyboard)

How to prevent floating keyboard in one of the few TextFields, if you have several TextFields?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615806/disable-uitextfield-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Set the text field's delegate to `self` and implement

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  return NO;
}
```