# How do I set a UITextField as the default input field at app launch

Tags: ios, cursor, uitextfield, default

I am writing an iPhone app with a keypad and two TextFields on a single view. The user types into each of the text fields. Because I want to use an on-screen keypad, I disabled the the keyboard from launching when each TextField is selected. (I used the method suggested in this thread:

> [Disable UITextField keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615806/disable-uitextfield-keyboard)

So far so good EXCEPT the cursor doesn't blink in the either of the two TextFields until they are selected. If I just begin typing without selecting, the first textfield is filled. That's OK, but I would like to set the cursor flashing in that field so the user is notified that that is where the input will go unless they select the other field.

I did not create the text fields programatically. I created them with Interface builder.

1. How do I programatically select the desired starting text field (ideally some highlight would show up when selected). Right now I just got lucky and the field I want to be the default is the default.
2. How do I place the flashing cursor onto the right side of that text field.

...Dale

Answer (score 4):

Call [`[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder) this will notify the receiver that it is about to become first responder in its window. That should set the Cursor in the UITextField.

Answer (score 2):

To programmatically activate a field and make it your starting text field you should use `UIResponder's` [becomeFirstResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method, which all `UITextFields` inherit from.

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Thanks 8vius. I saw Joe's response first. You probably posted it at the same time. Your collective answer worked great!