# How to disable keyboard when clicking a UITextField in iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I am currently developing a prototype that I want to do user testing on desktop first before loading to iPad.

I am looking for solutions to disable the keyboard after clicking a textfield. That means after clicking a textfield, user is able to enter information from the macbook keyboard directly, and the virtual keyboard that automatically shows up in the simulator will not appear. I have been through a lot of tutorials but they are all dismissing the keyboard after user entry; that is not what I am looking for. How should I hide the keyboard?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];    
myTextField.inputView = dummyView; // Hide keyboard, but show blinking cursor
```

It works for UITextField and UITextView and they need to be set to editable.

**What you did Here:**
You created a dummy view of `width=hight=0`, & assigned it as the inputView of your `textField`.

**How It works:**
Instead of showing default, keyboard, now, the viewController is showing `DummyView` as `inputView` for your `UITextField`. As DummyView has `Width=height=0`, You will not see anything on the screen  :)

Comment: @Prince Agrawal It does not work with ipad air2. Its shows keyboard toolbar at the bottom of screen.Could you help with this.

Comment: @hardikhadwani This is not device specific. What do you mean by keyboard toolbar?

Comment: If i run app in ipad air2 iOS 9 this is not working. It is showing system copy,undo and redo tool bar.

Comment: This creates a zombie object and crashes my app when the view is deallocated. So... thanks, but no thanks.

Comment: Really Great!! Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350573/1752988) which I found the same hack but with little additional supportive code snippet to hide the blinking cursor too.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;  // Hides both keyboard and blinking cursor.
}
```

I needed this to be done for a Quantity text field where I increase/decrease the quantity using a UIStepper view. So I needed the keyboard to be hidden always.

Answer (score 1):

This will set the `inputView` of your textField to, basically, an empty `UIView` with no frame.

```
self.theTextField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```